# Twitter Bootstrap: Printing select elements

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, printing

In Chrome twitter bootstrap select elements cause a bug where it looks like the shadows are stretched vertically.

[image]

That image is from the Twitter Bootstrap site itself so it looks like a bug with the framework (although I've seen comments in the github repo that they're not too concerned about print issues). I've tried setting all effects classes to none but that doesn't seem to remove the glitch.

I still need Bootstrap for the layout but I guess I could make a custom print version without form styles but I'm hoping there's a quick fix instead.

thanks!

Comment: Just speculating: are you only running into this issue on a Mac?

Comment: dont see any issue on my chrome latest

Comment: Ran into this too using Bootstrap and the latest version of Chrome.  It isn't really a solution, but ended up binding the selected value to another element and applying CSS styles to only show the select on the screen and the other element on print.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and just rewrote this css rule:

```
@media print {
    * { background: transparent !important; }
}
```

to:

```
@media print {
    select { background: #fff !important; }
}
```